# How can I use a variable to make a list in a form?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have my variables working and I have an array I want to cycle through to add text to a list of each of the variables in my array. Any ideas on what im doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var enteredText = ""
    @State var textItems: [String] = []
    
    private func updateTextItems(){
        textItems.append(enteredText)
        print("---------------")
        for i in textItems {
            print(i)
        }
        print("---------------")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Add Item to Array")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Enter Text", text: $enteredText)
                        Button("Save", action: updateTextItems)
                        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Items")){
                        ForEach(textItems) {textItems in
                            HStack{
                                Text(textItems)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Array Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all that foreach statement needs to fire compile error :). I think this one is working :)

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var enteredText = ""
@State var textItems: [String] = []

private func updateTextItems(){
    textItems.append(enteredText)
    print("---------------")
    for i in textItems {
        print(i)
    }
    print("---------------")
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Add Item to Array")) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Enter Text", text: $enteredText)
                    Button("Save", action: updateTextItems)
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Items")){
                    ForEach(textItems, id: \.self) {textItems in
                        HStack{
                            Text(textItems)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Array Test")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect. This did exactly what I wanted it to do. Thanks!